# Weird Import Error in TypeScript when importing from SASS package: exported function doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, sass

With the [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/) package, I'm simply trying to transpile a SASS string into a CSS one, but on the `import` line:

```js
import { compileString } from 'sass';

const scss = `
  div {
    .row {
      display: flex;
    }
  }
`;

const css = compileString(s);

console.log(css);
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './../../../node_modules/sass/sass.default.js' does not provide an export named 'compileString';
```

But the `compileString` function does exist, and it's a top-level export. What's going on here?

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/lib/payments.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Works for me in the playground... https://tsplay.dev/WzGZLw what version of SASS are you using?

Comment: Is that a runtime error or TypeScript error?

Comment: Runtime error, TS doesn't complain.

Comment: Soooo what does TypeScript have to do with this error? Are you using a bundler of some sort?

Comment: As somebody who doesn't know the solution to this problem, I don't know if TS is influencing it or not.